# Dagger, how to create DAO module

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-2

I need some help on how to implement Dagger in an app using ROOM, I'm stuck on creating a module for the DAO interface.

daoModule

```
@Module
abstract class daoModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun provideDao(dao: WordDao): WordDao
}
```

Error

```
 public abstract com.example.daggerroom.Room.WordDao provideDao(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                        ^C:\Android\DaggerRoom\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\example\daggerroom\di\AppComponent.java:6: error:
```

I would appreciate any comments on this as I've been stuck on this for over a week and I'm just not sure how to implement Dagger with Room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to be able to provide an instance of Database and then you can get your Dao from the Db:

```kotlin
@Module
abstract class DaoModule {
    companion object {
        
        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideDatabase(application: Application): YourDb {
            return Room.databaseBuilder(application, YourDb.class, "db").build()
        }

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideWordDao(database: YourDb): WordDao {
            return database.getWordDao()
        }
    }

    // Binds methods...
}
```